# Get Context from String (Android)

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the Context from a string like `"com.example.myApp.MainActivity"`?

i am working with `AlarmManager` and want to cancel an alarm even after closing and reopening the App from all activities. I save the `requestCode`of the `PendingIntent` in a table, which works well, if i try to cancel it in the same activity (after reopening the app).

But if i want to cancel it in another activity, i have to set the same context as set before. I thought about saving the context as a string and read it before cancelling from the table.

is this even possible or is there a better solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case everything what you need is a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

So in here you just create a Service, which will be completely independent and always alive ;) And you can send very easily messages to your Service. I think that's the best for Alarm functionality :) So at the end, you don't need to have some dirty solution with static string to get a context.

Comment: Propably this is the better solution.